# Removing Password Requests

Tags: password

I want to remove ALL password requests on Ubuntu. My PC is one-user without proper keyboard since its a HTPC. I have already done the following:

1. `sudo visual` and changed by adding `NOPASSWD`
2. Edited `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`, removed `#` at the start of the password line and changed `yes` to `no`.

I still get password request, sometimes at the start of the session and sometimes in other cases. And I am not referring to `sudo` statements within a Terminal.

Comment: @damadam. Any feedback? Thx

Comment: Ubuntu also still asking me for a login

Answer (score 0):

Use visudo to edit the sudoers file (never try to change it any other way!):

```
sudo visudo
```

then paste the following line at the end;

```
user ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

at the end of `/etc/sudoers`. Replace user with the name of your current user.
so if your user is *babek* you enter

```
babek ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

at the end of `/etc/sudoers`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Tried it, but I still got a "Enter password to unlock your login keyring" message. Regarding your comment, I sudo visudo and added babek ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL at the end of the file. Saved and existed. Checked and my changed was there. Thx